# Symfony Form with Doctrine Entity - Relation not loading for editing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm having an issue with something I think is probably fairly basic but the cause is escaping me.

I have a two entities, an Organisation and a Subscription. An organisation is linked with one subscription.

I want to be able to edit this via a form (creating via form already works). When I do the following:

```
    $organisation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Organisation')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'id' => $id
        ));

    $form = $this->createForm(new OrganisationType(), $organisation, array(
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));

    $form->submit($paramFetcher->all());
```

I get an exception because the subscription property of the organisation entity is not set (despite passing one which has a subscription into the form defaults). The exception is as follows:

```
Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Subscription", "NULL" given
```

This is obviously being thrown by the setSubscription method on the Organisation entity but I'm not sure why as the form should be converting the int value passed to a Subscription entity automatically.

Am I doing something stupid here? I have attached the relevant code below. Thank you!

**The simplest controller action that replicates this issue**

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{

    $organisation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Organisation')
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => 7));

    $form = $this->createForm(new OrganisationType(), $organisation);

    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    return $this->render('test.html.twig', array(
        'testform' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

**Organisation.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Organisation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="organisation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OrganisationRepository")
 */
class Organisation
{

const ENABLED = 1;
const DISABLED = 2;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var Subscription|null The subscription this organisation is currently linked to
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subscription", inversedBy="organisations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscription_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="set null")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $subscription;

/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="organisation")
 * @JMS\Groups({})
 */
private $users;

/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subgroup", mappedBy="organisation")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default"})
 */
private $subgroups;

/**
 * @var string $enabled
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $enabled = self::ENABLED;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Organisation
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Sets subscription
 *
 * @param Subscription $subscription
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSubscription(Subscription $subscription)
{
    $this->subscription = $subscription;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Gets subscription
 *
 * @return Subscription|null
 */
public function getSubscription()
{
    return $this->subscription;
}

/**
 * Sets enabled
 *
 * @param $enabled
 */
public function setEnabled($enabled)
{
    if (!in_array($enabled, array(self::ENABLED, self::DISABLED))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid enabled status');
    }

    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

/**
 * Gets enabled
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEnabled()
{
    return $this->enabled;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Returns Users belonging to this organisation
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
}
```

**Subscription.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Organisation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscription")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SubscriptionRepository")
 */
class Subscription
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @JMS\Groups({"default", "list-organisation"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Organisation", mappedBy="subscription")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default"})
 */
private $organisations;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default"})
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @JMS\Groups({"default"})
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Subscription
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Returns Organisations with this subscription type
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getOrganisations()
{
    return $this->organisations;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
}
```

**OrganisationType.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class OrganisationType extends AbstractType
{
private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->manager = $objectManager;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('subscription', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Subscription'
    ));

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Organisation',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: First, why are you using a DataTransformer on that entity field ? Symfony is natively able to transform an integer (provided by the select field of your form) into an object, as long as you provide the Class to use, which you did in the field options. Secondly, can you provide the exception thrown please ?

Comment: @VaN Hi there, I had the transformer in just to check ensure it was converting. It is unnecessary and I have removed it since. I have edited my post to show the actual exception. Thanks for your help, this one is driving me nuts!

Comment: The only thing I am not familiar with is your way to handle form submission. I never used `$form->submit($paramFetcher->all())`. According to the documentation, the way to handle form is submission is the following : `$form->handleRequest($request); 
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $organisation = $form->getData();

        // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database`
see http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: Hi @VaN, interestingly enough using handleRequest does not actually submit the form for me. If I use that and then call `isValid` the form behaves as though it has not been submitted. The `$form->submit($paramFetcher->all())` is suggested in the docs for submitting a form directly. I'm sure there is something remarkably stupid I'm missing here, but I just can't see it.

Comment: can you post your whole controller action ? which version of symfony2 are you using ?

Comment: @VaN No problem, I have edited my post to include a simple controller action that results in this issue. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i'm installing a fresh sf3.1 app, and replicate your app to investigate on it. will post here soon

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh Symfony 3.1, this works like a charm (and this is the recommended way to handle form submission, as stated in a previous comment) :

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $organisation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Organisation')
        ->find(1);

    $form = $this->createForm(OrganisationType::class, $organisation);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($organisation);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        die('saved into database.');
    }

    return $this->render('test.html.twig', array(
        'testform' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort. I haven't located the source of this, though I suspect it may be something to do with serialization groups or something. I've had to move on for the time being but I'll update the question with the answer when I get back on it.